# iPhone: Play videos automatically in a sequence, one after another

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, ipod

i built a very basic video player app in Xcode 4.3.2
i have 3 small videos and on my main menu i have 3 buttons. One button for each video
my code looks like this.....

```
- (IBAction)playMoviePressed1:(id)sender 
{

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                  pathForResource:@"HomeVideoOne" ofType:@"m4v"];

player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
          initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
}
```

And it repeats for videos 2 and 3.  I would like to have a 4th button that played all 3 videos in order without stopping and having to select the next one.  It's almost like having to play chapters in a movie one at a time.

Here's the kicker,  I don't want to make any extra video files to add to the project size.  So in other words the only way i am able to accomplish my goal so far is to edit all 3 videos into one .m4v file and import that to the project. But that is no good because it doubles my project size.  I'd like to call on the existing files to play in one right after another with no break. I hope I didn't sound to repetitious.
Thank You
-ANthony

Comment: Merging three videos in one is not gonna help you reduce app size. If you want all videos to be played in offline mode you gotta compromise with application size.

Comment: You can show this videos in tableView and play respective video on selecting them. If you want to achieve this let me know I implemented it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you will need to use some more advanced API like `AVQueuePlayer` instead of a basic `MPMoviePlayerController`
Try look through the document here first http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html

Comment: +1 for correct answer. To straighten all of this up a little: you may certainly use MPMoviePlayerController for playing the videos with a little drawback; that option **will** lead to small gaps (pre buffering time). To get rid of this drawback, the correct option is using AVQueuePlayer. That option however again has a drawback, there is no user interface provided for you and you will have to design and implement that yourself.

Comment: @Till You're absolutely correct and I also think `AVQueuePlayer` is a better approach but the pre-buffering time is negligible for local files. Another downside of `AVQueuePlayer` is the limited support (iOS 4.1 and later)!

Answer (score 0):

You can always start another video whenever a video is finished playing. One way is to set your custom methods to be called to control the behavior when you create `youMoviePlayerController`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
               selector:@selector(aMoviePlaybackComplete:)
                   name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                 object:youMoviePlayerController];
```

and then:

```
- (void)aMoviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification*)notification
{
  MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
  if(urlIndex < yourUrlArray.count){
     NSUrl* myUrl = [yourUrlArray objectAtIndex:urlIndex];
     [moviePlayerController setContentURL:myUrl];
     [moviePlayerController play];
     urlIndex++;
  }
  else{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:moviePlayerController];

     [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
     [moviePlayerController release];
  }
}
```

I'm assuming `yourUrlArray` is a pre-defined array of the urls of the movies you want to play and `urlIndex` is keeping count of the current movie being played. Of course, you'll have to tune this to your needs.

**EDIT-** For local files, you can form the `NSUrl` using `bundle`:

```
NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSUrl* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
[yourUrlArray addObject:url];
```

and initialize the url array(`yourUrlArray`) and then continue as posted before.

Comment: @Tipycalflow...I think you got me on the right track.  However the videos are part of my project and not called using a URL. Let's say my video files are called "carman1.m4v carman2.m4v and carman3.m4v". These files are in my project folder and added to my project. Could you possibly answer my question again.  I'm a bit new at all this. Thank you for getting me on the right path. Stack over flow is flipping' awesome!!!!!!!

Comment: Also I should state that I want to have the option to play the videos individually. One button per video and then one button that is a "play all" button that would accomplish what my original question asked.  Thanks